# cannot snap-exec: cannot exec "/snap/dotnet-sdk/152/snap/command-chain/snapcraft-runner": permission denied

Tags: .net, sdk

**The dotnet command cannot be executed after installing snap**

I followed these instructions to install the .NET 6.0 preview using snap.

After installation, when I try to execute the dotnet command, I get the following error message:

cannot snap-exec: cannot exec "/snap/dotnet-sdk/152/snap/command-chain/snapcraft-runner": permission denied
This is because the directory /snap/dotnet-sdk/152/snap is only accessible by root and is a mounted file system, so it is not possible to chmod it.

I am using a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install, so there should not be any other conflicts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears to be problem with snap alias. Just unalias the snap and symlink the binary instead.

```
sudo snap unalias dotnet
sudo ln -s /snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet
```

You should then be able to call `dotnet --list-sdks` without root permission.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice

Answer (score 0):

```
# Install the .NET 6 SDK as a snap package.
# The snap package will automatically be mounted.
snap install dotnet-sdk --channel=6.0/beta --classic

# Try running the snap command. If this works, you do not have to
# apply the workaround. If this fails, continue.
dotnet-sdk.dotnet --version

# To find out where the snap package has been mounted,
# list all block devices and look for /snap/dotnet-sdk/
# in the MOUNTPOINT column. Remember the name of the loop
# device.
lsblk

# To get the actual path of the snap package file, run
# The path in the BACK-FILE column points to the snap package.
losetup --list

# Replace XXX with the number of your snap.
# find the /var/lib/snapd/snaps/dotnet-sdk_XXX.snap in the list
# Create a folder where we're extracting the snap package into.
mkdir dotnet-snap-fix
cd dotnet-snap-fix

# Extract the snap package into this directory.
# Add the correct BACK-FILE path to your snap package here.
# Replace XXX or the whole path with the BACK-FILE displayed by
# the losetup command above.
sudo unsquashfs /var/lib/snapd/snaps/dotnet-sdk_XXX.snap

# Change the permissions of the snap folder containing the runner
# to be readable and executable. This will fix the permission problem.
sudo chmod -R +rx ./squashfs-root/snap/

# Create a new snap package with the changed permissions.
# Make sure to use the same file name as in the BACK-FILE path.
# Replace XXX or the whole file name with the file name of the
# BACK-FILE path displayed by the losetup command above.
sudo mksquashfs ./squashfs-root/ dotnet-sdk_XXX.snap -comp xz -all-root

# Overwrite the old snap package with our new one.
# Make sure the file name is correct (same as in BACK-FILE).
sudo mv ./dotnet-sdk_XXX.snap /var/lib/snapd/snaps/

# Finally reboot your machine so the changes are detected.
sudo reboot

# Do not use snap disable / snap enable, they will replace the
# fixed snap package with the broken one again.
# After the reboot, the dotnet-sdk.dotnet command will work without sudo.
dotnet-sdk.dotnet
```

reference to solution: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4446#issuecomment-605629427